# Can the EV3 software program switch block take inputs?

Tags: ev3

Is it possible to input values into a switch block? For example, if I have a move steering block in switch statement, can I input a value for power from a math block outside the switch statement? If I have a move steering block inside a switch, it looks like all I can do is set the slider value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to connect data wires from outside switch blocks and loop block to inside of them. Note: Switch blocks must be switched to the tabbed view by clicking on the [image] icon. Then just drag the output data wire from the math block to the input of the steering block the same as if the switch block was not there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave, the trick I was missing was that you need to be in tabbed view, it can't be done in flat view, correct?

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the case. Thanks for pointing that out. I will update my answer.